# When does useQuery trigger a re-render?

Tags: react-apollo

Client side state:

```
type State {
  a: Int!
  b: Int!
}
extend type Query {
  state: State!
}
```

React Component A:

```
query {
  state @client {
    a
  }
}
```

Will the following code trigger a re-render on component A?

```
client.writeData({
  data: {
    state: {
      ...prevState,
      b: prevState.b + 1,
     },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `writeData` to manually update the cache will change the data in the result object returned from `useQuery`. However, React is smart about re-renders and will only rerender if values from your query are actually being used in your JSX. Hope this helps.

Comment: What if we had another component B that used state.b? Will the ```writeData``` above trigger a re-render on A?

Comment: As the state object is replaced, I was expecting both components A and B to update when the state changes, as react does a shallow comparison to test equality.

But it looks like only the components whose values changes are updated.


Have a look here: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-proskuriakova-b3v3x
(May have to open in a new window for the counter buttons to work.)